# Is it possible to use the postgres LISTEN / NOTIFY with typeorm

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I know typeorm has listeners and subscribers that one can listen and subscribe to for events sent from repository/manager and querybuilder. However I would like to listen to postgres notifications. I have been able to successfully listen to them just using the pg package like this `Client.query( 'LISTEN the_notification;')`, but want to know if this can be done with typeorm so that I don't need to have two connections, one with just pg and the other as a datasource for typeorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a git thread, https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2436.
I guess this is not possible at the moment